# What mechanism is responsible for removing empty consumer groups from a Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka

**The problem:**
My Kafka cluster has records of empty consumer groups, with non-zero committed offset, being 2-3 years old. I know they are that old since their names include a creation timestamp. This results in 100 000+ consumer groups of which probably > 99.9% are obsolete. My cluster's `offsets.retention.minutes` property is set to 43200 (30 days). I want to understand why these groups are not removed.

**Observations:**
Here is an example, a group created back in 2019 with 0 members and non-zero committed offset:

```
Consumer group 'SingleConsumer-2019-09-26T17:04:02.520Z-4edccc31-eaf5-4977-b106-4119357a76f0' has no active members.

GROUP                               COORDINATOR (ID)          ASSIGNMENT-STRATEGY  STATE           #MEMBERS
SingleConsumer-2019-09-26T17:04:02.520Z-4edccc31-eaf5-4977-b106-4119357a76f0 kafkanode5.company.net:6668 (1005)                      Empty           0

GROUP                                                                        TOPIC                                PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
SingleConsumer-2019-09-26T17:04:02.520Z-4edccc31-eaf5-4977-b106-4119357a76f0 Company.Audit.Prod 0          127616          538691823       538564207 

  -               -               -
```

What I do not understand is:

1. Why the committed offset for this group has not been discarded after `offsets.retention.minutes` period (30 days) has passed?
2. Why is this group still in the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

The consumer offsets topic works like any other compacted topic. There's 50 partitions, for that topic, and a log cleaner thread that only removes closed log segments, or compacts based on how "dirty" a particular segment is. The offsets retention config is only a lower bound for when log segments will be *attempted* to be removed, not a per-group TTL

If you have random timestamp / UUID in your group names, it's possible they get hashed into some rarely used log segment, that has remained open for a long time.

You can also check your log cleaner logs to see if those segments are ever being read